# How to avoid 'Step In' while debugging using Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio

[image]

For any initialization or variable declaration like `string x = new string()`,..

in above image its for `Hashtable htmessage = new hashtable();`

Comment: press `F10` instead `F11`

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29780510/ignore-a-project-in-visual-studio-while-debugging

Comment: Your question is unclear. You claim to have code that reads `Hashtable htmessage = new hashtable();`, but that would not compile, and it's not clear which hash table class you meant to refer to. Normally, VS won't try to step into external code, so if the `Hashtable` in question is from .NET, you just need to turn off stepping into external code (if that's the case, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32048766/what-is-just-my-code)

Comment: Thank You for helping 

Answer (score 2):

`F11` will "**Step Into**", where `F10` will "**Step Over**"

[image]

See the documentation [Code Stepping Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ek13f001(v=vs.85).aspx)

> Step Into and Step Over differ in only one respect, the way they
>   handle function calls. Either command instructs the debugger to
>   execute the next line of code. If the line contains a function call,
>   Step Into executes only the call itself, then halts at the first line
>   of code inside the function. Step Over executes the entire function,
>   then halts at the first line outside the function. Use Step Into if
>   you want to look inside the function call. Use Step Over if you want
>   to avoid stepping into functions.